# 'React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h' file not found after updating react-native from 0.59 to 0.61.4

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native

I recently updated my project that was using react-native 0.59 to 0.61.4.

The android build works just fine but the ios fails with error :

> 'React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h' file not found

On my project message extension. I tried all the main fixes for this issues like:

1. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12077#issuecomment-302318906
2. Trying to create a React scheme, which I wasn't able to do it because React isn't shown when I try to create the scheme.

**My Podfile**

```
platform :ios, '9.0' require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target 'Project' do   # Pods for Project   pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"   pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"   pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"   pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"   pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'   pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'   pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'   pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'   pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'   pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'   pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'   pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'   pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'   pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'   pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'   pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'   pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'   pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'   pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'   pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'   pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'   pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'   pod 'ReactCommon/jscallinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"   pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"   pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'   pod 'RNDeviceInfo', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-device-info'   pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec' pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'   pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'   pod 'RNKeychain', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-keychain'   pod 'react-native-background-timer', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-background-timer'   pod 'react-native-udp', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-udp'   pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'  pod 'react-native-fingerprint-scanner', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fingerprint-scanner'   pod 'react-native-randombytes', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-randombytes'   pod 'RNSVG', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-svg'

  target 'ProjectTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing   end

  target 'ProjectMessageExtension' do
    inherit! :search_paths   end

  use_native_modules! end

target 'Project-tvOS' do   # Pods for Project-tvOS

  target 'Project-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing   end

end
```

**My package.json**

```
{
  "name": "Project",
  "version": "1.2.1",
  "private": true,
  "description": "",
  "homepage": "",
  "bugs": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "build:android": "react-native run-android",
    "build:ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "release:android": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease",
    "release:android-bundle": "cd android && ./gradlew bundleRelease",
    "link": "./node_modules/.bin/rn-nodeify --hack --install && node ./scripts/androidSdkFix.js",
    "test": "jest --config ./jest.config.js --env=jsdom",
    "test:live": "npm test -- --watch",
    "test:format": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint ./",
    "test:android": "cd android && ./gradlew --project-cache-dir ../.gradlecache test",
    "i18n": "node ./scripts/scanner.config.js",
    "test:build-e2e-release": "detox build --configuration ios.sim.release",
    "test:build-e2e-debug": "detox build --configuration ios.sim.debug",
    "test:e2e-clean": "detox clean-framework-cache && detox build-framework-cache",
    "test:e2e-release": "node ./node_modules/cucumber/bin/cucumber-js e2e --format node_modules/cucumber-pretty --configuration ios.sim.release",
    "test:e2e-debug": "node ./node_modules/cucumber/bin/cucumber-js e2e --format node_modules/cucumber-pretty --configuration=ios.sim.debug",
    "prettier": "prettier 'src/**/*.js'",
    "eslint-check": "eslint --print-config .eslintrc.js | eslint-config-prettier-check"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./src/assets/fonts/"
    ]
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.js": "eslint"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged",
      "pre-push": "npm test"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.5.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "3.2.1",
    "@react-navigation/core": "^3.4.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^3.5.0",
    "@remobile/react-native-qrcode-local-image": "github:yasharAyari/react-native-qrcode-local-image#support-import-from-cameraroll",
    "@tradle/react-native-http": "^2.0.1",
    "assert": "^1.4.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "base-x": "=3.0.4",
    "bignumber.js": "^7.2.1",
    "bip32": "^1.0.2",
    "bitcoinjs-lib": "^4.0.3",
    "browserify-zlib": "^0.1.4",
    "buffer": "^4.9.1",
    "buffer-reverse": "^1.0.1",
    "console-browserify": "^1.1.0",
    "constants-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "dns.js": "^1.0.1",
    "domain-browser": "^1.2.0",
    "events": "^1.1.1",
    "fetch-mock": "^7.2.5",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "hoist-non-react-statics": "^3.1.0",
    "https-browserify": "0.0.1",
    "i18next": "^13.1.2",
    "lottie-react-native": "^3.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.0",
    "path-browserify": "0.0.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "punycode": "^1.4.1",
    "querystring-es3": "^0.2.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-i18next": "^9.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.61.4",
    "react-native-app-settings": "github:KrazyLabs/react-native-app-settings",
    "react-native-background-timer": "^2.1.0-alpha.6",
    "react-native-blur-overlay": "github:yasharAyari/react-native-blur-overlay",
    "react-native-camera": "^2.11.1",
    "react-native-camera-roll-picker": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-crypto": "^2.1.2",
    "react-native-device-info": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-dropdownalert": "^3.9.2",
    "react-native-fingerprint-scanner": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-haptic-feedback": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-http": "github:tradle/react-native-http#834492d",
    "react-native-interactable": "1.0.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-tracking-view": "^5.5.0",
    "react-native-keychain": "=3.0.0",
    "react-native-level-fs": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^6.1.0",
    "react-native-modalbox": "^1.7.1",
    "react-native-os": "^1.2.4",
    "react-native-permissions": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^5.1.0",
    "react-native-quick-actions": "^0.3.9",
    "react-native-randombytes": "^3.5.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-shake": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.7.5",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^8.0.11",
    "react-native-svg-uri": "=1.2.3",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0-rc.3",
    "react-native-switch-pro": "^1.0.0-beta",
    "react-native-tcp": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-udp": "^2.6.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.0.2",
    "react-navigation": "^3.12.1",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3",
    "react-transform-hmr": "^1.0.4",
    "readable-stream": "^1.0.33",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-connect-decorator": "^0.2.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.1.1",
    "stream-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "string_decoder": "^0.10.31",
    "text-encoding": "^0.6.4",
    "timers-browserify": "^1.4.2",
    "tty-browserify": "0.0.0",
    "url": "^0.10.3",
    "url-parse": "^1.4.4",
    "util": "^0.10.4",
    "vm-browserify": "0.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-stage-2": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.3",
    "asyncstorage-down": "^4.0.1",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "=8.0.2",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-rewrite-require": "^1.14.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "coveralls": "^3.0.2",
    "cucumber": "5.1.0",
    "cucumber-pretty": "1.5.0",
    "detox": "14.5.0",
    "eslint": "=4.18.2",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "=15.1.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "=12.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "=4.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-detox": "1.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "=2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "=21.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "=7.4.0",
    "findit": "^2.0.0",
    "glob": "^7.1.3",
    "husky": "^1.0.0-rc.13",
    "i18next-scanner": "^2.9.1",
    "jest": "24.8.0",
    "jest-cli": "^24.8.0",
    "jest-junit": "^5.2.0",
    "jest-runner-eslint": "^0.6.0",
    "jest-transform-stub": "^1.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^8.1.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.55.0",
    "moxios": "^0.4.0",
    "prettier": "1.18.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3",
    "redux-connect-decorator": "^0.2.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3",
    "rn-nodeify": "github:tradle/rn-nodeify",
    "schedule": "^0.4.0"
  },
  "react-native": {
    "zlib": "browserify-zlib",
    "console": "console-browserify",
    "constants": "constants-browserify",
    "crypto": "react-native-crypto",
    "dns": "dns.js",
    "net": "react-native-tcp",
    "domain": "domain-browser",
    "http": "@tradle/react-native-http",
    "https": "https-browserify",
    "os": "react-native-os",
    "path": "path-browserify",
    "querystring": "querystring-es3",
    "fs": "react-native-level-fs",
    "_stream_transform": "readable-stream/transform",
    "_stream_readable": "readable-stream/readable",
    "_stream_writable": "readable-stream/writable",
    "_stream_duplex": "readable-stream/duplex",
    "_stream_passthrough": "readable-stream/passthrough",
    "dgram": "react-native-udp",
    "stream": "stream-browserify",
    "timers": "timers-browserify",
    "tty": "tty-browserify",
    "vm": "vm-browserify",
    "tls": false
  },
  "browser": {
    "zlib": "browserify-zlib",
    "console": "console-browserify",
    "constants": "constants-browserify",
    "crypto": "react-native-crypto",
    "dns": "dns.js",
    "net": "react-native-tcp",
    "domain": "domain-browser",
    "http": "@tradle/react-native-http",
    "https": "https-browserify",
    "os": "react-native-os",
    "path": "path-browserify",
    "querystring": "querystring-es3",
    "fs": "react-native-level-fs",
    "_stream_transform": "readable-stream/transform",
    "_stream_readable": "readable-stream/readable",
    "_stream_writable": "readable-stream/writable",
    "_stream_duplex": "readable-stream/duplex",
    "_stream_passthrough": "readable-stream/passthrough",
    "dgram": "react-native-udp",
    "stream": "stream-browserify",
    "timers": "timers-browserify",
    "tty": "tty-browserify",
    "vm": "vm-browserify",
    "tls": false
  },
  "detox": {
    "configurations": {
      "ios.sim.debug": {
        "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Project.app",
        "build": "xcodebuild -UseModernBuildSystem=NO -project ios/Project.xcodeproj -scheme Project -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "name": "iPhone 11"
      },
      "ios.sim.release": {
        "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Project.app",
        "build": "xcodebuild -UseModernBuildSystem=NO -project ios/Project.xcodeproj -scheme Project -configuration Release -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "name": "iPhone 11"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After 0.61 update React can not implemented as Scheme. You need to install from your **Podfile**.

Check this out, [0.61 Changes](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2019/09/18/version-0.61)

> If you want things to work as before, just upgrade your project to
>   0.60.5.

After upgrading 0.61 or up, you can try,

- Removing Derived Data with `File` > `Workspace Settings` click over
  the little grey arrow under Derived data section and select your
  project folder to delete it.
- Removing React(missing) target from your scheme. `Product` > `Scheme`> `Edit Scheme` > `Build` you can see the ex React scheme as **React(missing)**. Just remove it and add from new React scheme from your Pods.

In your Podfile React implemented as,

```
pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
```

You should change it like this,

```
 pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
```

After change remove Pods and Podfile.lock and re-install your Pods.

```
cd ios/
rm -rf Pods/ && Podfile.lock
pod install
```

One last thing, you can check your Podfile with this [upgrade helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried that and it didn't work... I have compared my project to upgrade helper but it seems to be the same. I don't know if I'm targeting my extension in the wrong way (because that's something they don't cover in the helper) or something like that... I can't find any case similar to mine in stack-overflow :(

Comment: @RaquelCasadoDias Please check my edited answer above. I had face the same issues over 5 projects and almost every project had different solutions. This 61 upgrade is just pain in ios.